farcaster frame development issue
I'm building farcaster frame app with frog.
Issue is when I paste https://ggframe.xyz/donate/8453/9/0 on warpcast,
button1 doesn't recognize params after 8453 like attached capture even though button2 recognizes them.
but when I paste https://ggframe.xyz/api/donate/8453/9/0 on warpcast, it works perfectly fine.
what is wrong on API route or frame implementation? Repo is here.


on localhost, both works fine

The /api route is needed because all frames in nextjs are configured in the api route located in the pages or app directory during your setup.
